# Given an arc with a known start(x, y), end(x, y) and angle, how can I calculate its bounding box?

Tags: python, math, geometry, bounding-box

The title says it all. Given an arc with (for example):

```
Start Point: x = 53.34, y = 52.07
End Point: x = 13.97, y = 52.07
Angle: 180 degrees
```

[image]
How can I find its bounding box?

Even though I am writing in python, puesdocode is preferred, so that it will be useful to other people.

Thanks!

-Tom

Comment: The information (start point, end point, angle) doesn't uniquely identify an arc. In your example it could also be the other half of the circle (or for that one the angle would be -180?).

Comment: In that case, can I make the assumption that a positive angle always means a specific direction? (ie: angle = -180 for the other half of the circle)

Comment: I think that [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net) or [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com) would be more appropriate places for this question. As an answer to your question: I suppose you can. But in order to be rigorous, use positive angle values for trigonometric (counter-clockwise) angles.

Comment: My apologies. Is there a move-question mechanism?

Comment: Not sure (I don't think so). But you already have an answer here, so I guess it's OK.

Comment: Your question says arc (just the outside) but your image is a sector (including two radii). Do you really mean arc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h = Sqrt( (start.x - end.x)^2 + (start.y - end.y)^2)
or
h = Math.Hypot(start.x - end.x, start.y - end.y)

R = Abs(h / (2*Sin(Angle/2)))

if angle <= Pi/2
    top = end.y
    left = end.x
    bottom = start.y
    right = start.x
else if angle <= Pi 
    top = start.y - R
    left = end.x
    bottom = start.y
    right = start.x
else if angle <= 3*Pi/2 
    top = start.y - R
    left = start.x - 2*R
    bottom = end.y
    right = start.x
else 
    top = start.y - R
    left = start.x - 2*R
    bottom = start.y + R
    right = start.x
```

Comment: Awesome! my python version: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSElRZk90cnh4dWs

Comment: Actually, I am not sure it is working - I am expecting to see a difference between the top and bottom (height of bounding box) to be 39.370.

Comment: For your example R = (53.34-13.97)/2=39.37/2=19.685 - this is box height. It's width is 39.37.

Comment: When I calculate R using your formula I get a vastly different answer. Not sure what I am doing wrong? 
http://pastebin.com/bukZjhPu

Comment: I forgot square root for distance (h) calculation. Edited. If you have `Math.Hypot` function, use it to find h.

Comment: Ok, now the value of R is correct. The code hits the angle <= Pi branch, but it looks like the top value is incorrect. Perhaps it should be start.y - 2*R? That seems to give the correct value however not sure about the other code branches.

Comment: Look at your picture. Vertical difference is R (circle radius)

Comment: Correct, my bad. On a side note, I think you just found a bug in the software I was using. Regardless, Thanks!